# How to send OpenTelemetry traces to Honeycomb.io directly from browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, open-telemetry

I've been trying to build an OpenTelemetry implementation which sends traces directly to Honeycomb.io.

```
// tracer.js
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';
import { WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http';

const HONEYCOMB_DATASET = '<DATA_SET>';
const HONEYCOMB_TEAM = '<API_KEY>';
const HONEYCOMB_URL = `https://api.honeycomb.io:443/v1/traces/`;
const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
  url: HONEYCOMB_URL,
  headers: {
    'X-Honeycomb-Team': HONEYCOMB_TEAM,
    'X-Honeycomb-Dataset': HONEYCOMB_DATASET,
  },
});

const provider = new WebTracerProvider();
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

export const tracer = provider.getTracer('default tracer');
```

If I later call

```
tracer.startSpan('link click').setAttributes(attributes).end();
```

I get a 501 response from `https://api.honeycomb.io/v1/traces/` with the body:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid content-type. Only application/protobuf is supported."
}
```

How do I send my traces as Protobufs?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the way Honeycomb recommends solving this problem is through a OpenTelemetry collector in-between your application and their API.

The idea is that you can send traces via HTTPS to your collector, via whatever form of security works for your infrastructure, and then have the collector massage your data before sending it to Honeycomb (thus keeping your Honeycomb API key from being exposed to the browser).

Source: https://www.honeycomb.io/blog/opentelemetry-browser-instrumentation/

---

I plan on updating this answer as Honeycomb updates their API to handle trace collection over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is updated now. You can send OTLP/HTTP traces using JSON to Honeycomb.io